Translate excel formulas into Redshift SQL query
I am looking for help to translate excel formulas into Redshift SQL . With given fixed input values for rows 1 (Month ascending) and 2 (SU - some number) I have to calculate through particular cells to get value for D8.

Complexity is, that formulas reference values in recurring levels/previous column/earlier months
Let me provide calculations for one column, as an example let's take column D
D1 - Month
D2 - SU 
D3 - C7 
D4 - C4 + B7
D5 - D3 * 1.54 + D4
D6 - D2 - D5
D7 - D6 / 2.38
D8 - D3 + D4 + D7

Below queries to build and populate exemplary table and populate it with data.

  CREATE TABLE TESTOSS
   (    PERIOD_MONTH VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    SU NUMBER
   );
   
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2020-09',503);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2020-10',1109);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2020-11',1537);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2020-12',2327);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-01',3000);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-02',4000);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-03',5000);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-04',3292);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-05',3721);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-06',4149);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-07',4578);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-08',5006);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-09',5435);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-10',5863);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-11',6292);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2021-12',6720);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2022-02',7577);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_MONTH,SU) values ('2022-01',7149);


This one was once solved in:
Translate excel formulas into SQL query
using an ORACLE function MODEL, which is not present in Redshift.
So far I didn't came up with the idea how to translate it properly.

`
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT
PERIOD_MONTH,
SU,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD_MONTH) AS rn,
0 AS t1,
0 AS t2,
0 AS rp_su,
0 AS n_su,
0 AS np,
0 AS tpe
FROM TESTOSS
UNION ALL
SELECT
t.PERIOD_MONTH,
t.SU,
t.rn,
c.np AS t1,
c.t2 + c.np AS t2,
c.t1 * 1.54 + c.t2 AS rp_su,
t.SU - c.t1 * 1.54 - c.t2 AS n_su,
(t.SU - c.t1 * 1.54 - c.t2) / 2.38 AS np,
c.t1 + c.t2 + (t.SU - c.t1 * 1.54 - c.t2) / 2.38 AS tpe
FROM TESTOSS t
JOIN cte c ON t.rn = c.rn + 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte; `

I could not test it as I dont have redshift, so putting it here in the comment.
I tried converting the oracle logic to redshift, let me know if it returns the expected output

This is a recursive problem so a recursive CTE is what you need.
SET UP:
CREATE TABLE testoss(    
   period_month VARCHAR(20), 
   su INT
);
   
INSERT INTO testoss (period_month, su) VALUES 
('2020-09',503),
('2020-10',1109),
('2020-11',1537),
('2020-12',2327),
('2021-01',3000),
('2021-02',4000),
('2021-03',5000),
('2021-04',3292),
('2021-05',3721),
('2021-06',4149),
('2021-07',4578),
('2021-08',5006),
('2021-09',5435),
('2021-10',5863),
('2021-11',6292),
('2021-12',6720),
('2022-02',7577),
('2022-01',7149);

QUERY:
WITH RECURSIVE build(period_month, su, t1, t2, rp_su, n_su, np, tpe, cur_rn, max_rn) AS (
   SELECT period_month, su, t1, t2, rp_su, n_su, np, tpe, cur_rn, max_rn
   from (SELECT period_month, su, 0::float AS t1, 0::float AS t2, 0::float AS rp_su, 
      su::float AS n_su, n_su / 2.38 AS np, np AS tpe, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD_MONTH) AS rn, 2::int as cur_rn, count(1) over() as max_rn
   FROM testoss ) where rn = 1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT t.period_month, t.su, b.np as t1, b.t2 + b.t1 AS t2,
      b.np * 1.54 + b.t2 + b.t1 AS rp_su, t.su - (b.np * 1.54 + b.t2 + b.t1) AS n_su, 
      (t.su - (b.np * 1.54 + b.t2 + b.t1)) / 2.38 AS np, b.np + b.t2 + b.t1 + (t.su - (b.np * 1.54 + b.t2 + b.t1)) / 2.38 AS tpe, 
      b.cur_rn + 1 AS cur_rn, b.max_rn
   FROM build b 
   JOIN (SELECT period_month, su, lag(period_month) over(order by period_month) prev_period, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD_MONTH) AS rn from testoss) t 
   ON t.prev_period = b.period_month
   WHERE t.rn = b.cur_rn AND b.cur_rn <= b.max_rn) 
SELECT period_month, su, t1, t2, rp_su, n_su, np, tpe FROM build order by period_month, cur_rn;

RESULT (CSV)
period_month,su,t1,t2,rp_su,n_su,np,tpe
2020-09,503,0,0,0,503,211.34453781512607,211.34453781512607
2020-10,1109,211.34453781512607,0,325.47058823529414,783.5294117647059,329.2140385565991,540.5585763717252
2020-11,1537,329.2140385565991,211.34453781512607,718.3341571922888,818.6658428077112,343.9772448771896,884.5358212489148
2020-12,2327,343.9772448771896,540.5585763717252,1070.2835334825972,1256.7164665174028,528.0321287888247,1412.5679500377396
2021-01,3000,528.0321287888247,884.5358212489148,1697.7052995837048,1302.2947004162952,547.1826472337375,1959.750597271477
2021-02,4000,547.1826472337375,1412.5679500377396,2255.229226777695,1744.7707732223048,733.0969635387836,2692.847560810261
2021-03,5000,733.0969635387836,1959.750597271477,3088.719921121204,1911.2800788787958,803.058856671763,3495.9064174820237
2021-04,3292,803.058856671763,2692.847560810261,3929.5582000847758,-637.5582000847758,-267.88159667427556,3228.0248208077483
2021-05,3721,-267.88159667427556,3495.9064174820237,3083.3687586036394,637.6312413963606,267.91228630099187,3495.9371071087403
2021-06,4149,267.91228630099187,3228.0248208077483,3640.6097417112755,508.39025828872445,213.60935222215315,3709.5464593308934
2021-07,4578,213.60935222215315,3495.9371071087403,3824.895509530856,753.1044904691439,316.4304581803126,4025.976917511206
2021-08,5006,316.4304581803126,3709.5464593308934,4196.849364928575,809.1506350714253,339.97925843337197,4365.956175944578
2021-09,5435,339.97925843337197,4025.976917511206,4549.544975498599,885.4550245014007,372.0399262610927,4737.9961022056705
2021-10,5863,372.0399262610927,4365.956175944578,4938.89766238666,924.1023376133398,388.2782931148487,5126.274395320519
2021-11,6292,388.2782931148487,4737.9961022056705,5335.9446736025375,956.0553263974625,401.70391865439603,5527.978313974915
2021-12,6720,401.70391865439603,5126.274395320519,5744.898430048289,975.1015699517111,409.7065419965173,5937.684855971433
2022-01,7149,409.7065419965173,5527.978313974915,6158.926388649552,990.0736113504481,415.9973156934656,6353.682171664898
2022-02,7577,415.9973156934656,5937.684855971433,6578.3207221393695,998.6792778606305,419.6131419582481,6773.295313623146

EXPLANATION

This recursive CTE plucks the first row off the test table and
calculates the few values that don't need previous rows' data.
Then this joined with the next row from the input table using the cur_rn column and row numbers of the source table.  The join is done by using a lag() to get the previous period_month and joining this with the previously created results.
Calculations only need t1 and t2 from the previous row which has been joined.
Calculate values of current row and iterate.

If you have questions just ask in a comment.

Maybe you could assist also with a similar one? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79204345/translate-excel-logic-formulas-into-redshift-sql-query
I was trying to do it by analogy, but after hours I've ended on a datatype mismatch  which I cannot trace: " Numeric column 4 precision and scales cannot be merged"

I took a peek and I don't see where you are getting a precision v. scale issue in the posted code.  Your google doc isn't open to the public, so no requirements seen.  The code isn't close to Redshift so not sure how to help.

With the sample data provided ...



period_month
su




2020-09
503


2020-10
1109


2020-11
1537


2020-12
2327


2021-01
3000


2021-02
4000


2021-03
5000


2021-04
3292


2021-05
3721


2021-06
4149


2021-07
4578


2021-08
5006


2021-09
5435


2021-10
5863


2021-11
6292


2021-12
6720


2022-02
7577


2022-01
7149



... create a recursive cte with your table selfjoined on two consecutive rows so you can have together the values from both rows ---
WITH 
  Recursive grid ( RN, KEY, PERIOD_MONTH, SU, rownum,  
                   t1_rownum, t1_period_month, t1_su
                 ) AS
    ( SELECT t.RN, t.KEY, t.PERIOD_MONTH, t.SU, t.rownum,  
             t1.rownum, t1.PERIOD_MONTH, t1.SU
      FROM ( Select       1 as RN, 'Month' as KEY, PERIOD_MONTH, SU, 
                          Row_Number() Over(Partition By 1 Order By PERIOD_MONTH) as rownum
             From       TESTOSS ) t
      INNER JOIN ( Select     1 as RN, 'Month' as KEY, PERIOD_MONTH, SU, 
                              Row_Number() Over(Partition By 1 Order By PERIOD_MONTH) as rownum, 
                              PERIOD_MONTH as "C"
                   From       TESTOSS ) t1 ON(t1.RN = t.RN And t1.rownum - 1 = t.rownum )
     Union All
      Select      RN + 1, Case When RN + 1 = 2 Then 'SU'
                               When RN + 1 = 3 Then 'T1'
                               When RN + 1 = 4 Then 'T2'
                               When RN + 1 = 5 Then 'RP_SU'
                               When RN + 1 = 6 Then 'N_SU'
                               When RN + 1 = 7 Then 'NP'
                               When RN + 1 = 8 Then 'TPE'
                         End, 
                 PERIOD_MONTH, SU, rownum, 
                 t1_rownum, t1_period_month, t1_su
      From       grid 
      Where      RN < 8
    ) 

... use Case expressions to "populate cells"
--      M a i n    S Q L :
Select    RN, KEY as "A", 
          Case When rownum = 1 And RN = 1 Then 'Dummy'::Varchar(32) Else 0::Varchar(32) End as "B",
          Case When rownum = 1 And RN = 1 Then PERIOD_MONTH::Varchar(32)
               When rownum = 1 And RN = 2 Then SU::Varchar(32)
               When rownum = 1 And RN = 3 Then  0::Varchar(32)
               When rownum = 1 And RN = 4 Then 0::Varchar(32)
               When rownum = 1 And RN = 5 Then 0::Varchar(32)
               When rownum = 1 And RN = 6 Then SU::Varchar(32)
               When rownum = 1 And RN = 7 Then Round(SU / 2.38, 4)::Varchar(32)
               When rownum = 1 And RN = 8 Then Round(SU / 2.38, 4)::Varchar(32)
          End as "C", 
            --
          Case When t1_rownum = 2 And RN = 1 Then t1_PERIOD_MONTH::Varchar(32)
               When t1_rownum = 2 And RN = 2 Then t1_SU::Varchar(32)
               When t1_rownum = 2 And RN = 3 Then Round(SU / 2.38, 4)::Varchar(32)    
               When t1_rownum = 2 And RN = 4 Then 0::Varchar(32)
               When t1_rownum = 2 And RN = 5 Then Round(Round(SU / 2.38, 4) * 1.54, 4)::Varchar(32)
               When t1_rownum = 2 And RN = 6 Then (t1_SU - Round(Round(SU / 2.38, 4) * 1.54, 4) )::Varchar(32)
               When t1_rownum = 2 And RN = 7 Then ( Round(( t1_SU - Round(Round(SU / 2.38, 4) * 1.54, 4) ) / 2.38, 4) )::Varchar(32)
               When t1_rownum = 2 And RN = 8 Then ( Round(SU / 2.38, 4) + 0 + (( Round(( t1_SU - Round(Round(SU / 2.38, 4) * 1.54, 4) ) / 2.38, 4) )) )::Varchar(32)
          End as "D"
From      grid
Where     rownum = 1
Order By  RN, rownum

R e s u l t :



rn
A
B
C
D




1
Month
Dummy
2020-09
2020-10


2
SU
0
503
1109


3
T1
0
0
211.3445


4
T2
0
0
0


5
RP_SU
0
0
325.4705


6
N_SU
0
503
783.5295


7
NP
0
211.3445
329.2141


8
TPE
0
211.3445
540.5586



fiddle
