"SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Numeric column 2 precision and scales cannot be merged" when coding logic in REdhsift
Such code gives me an error of: "SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Numeric column 2 precision and scales cannot be merged"
WITH RECURSIVE build (PERIOD_START_DATE,PEQ,PREV_PEQ,repeated_patient, cur_rn, max_rn) as (
select 
PERIOD_START_DATE,round(PEQ,1), round(cast(PREV_PEQ as float),1), round(cast(repeated_patient as float),1), cur_rn, max_rn from (       
select 
            PERIOD_START_DATE,
            PEQ,
            cast(PREV_PEQ as float),
            cast(repeated_patient as float),
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY period_start_date) AS rn
            , 2::int as cur_rn
            , count(1) over() as max_rn

from (select 
            PERIOD_START_DATE,
            round(1.0*SU_VALUE /6, 1)  PEQ,
            LAG(ROUND(1.0*SU_VALUE/6,1 ),1) OVER ( ORDER BY PERIOD_START_DATE ) PREV_PEQ, 
            cast(0 as float) as repeated_patient
      FROM testoss 
     ) where PEQ != PREV_PEQ  ) where rn=1
union all  
select  
            b.PERIOD_START_DATE,
            round(b.PEQ, 1),
            round(b.PREV_PEQ, 1),
 round(cast(case 
    when b.PREV_PEQ - nvl(t.repeated_patient,0) > b.PEQ then b.PEQ
    else b.PREV_PEQ - nvl(t.repeated_patient,0) 
  end as float), 1) as repeated_patient,
   b.cur_rn + 1 AS cur_rn,
   b.max_rn
  from build b join 
  (SELECT period_start_date, PEQ, PREV_PEQ, repeated_patient, lag(period_start_date) over(order by period_start_date) prev_period, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY period_start_date) AS rn from (SELECT 
            PERIOD_START_DATE,
            round(1.0*SU_VALUE /6, 1)  PEQ,
            LAG(ROUND(1.0*SU_VALUE/6,1 ),1) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD_START_DATE ) PREV_PEQ, 
            cast(0 as float) as repeated_patient
      FROM testoss 
     )) t ON t.prev_period = b.period_start_date
   WHERE t.rn = b.cur_rn AND b.cur_rn <= b.max_rn) 
   select   
            PERIOD_START_DATE,
            PEQ,
            PREV_PEQ,
            repeated_patient
            from build;

Given period date (PERIOD_START_DATE) and Standard units values (SU_VALUE) I need to code following requirements:
• Dosage: 6 tablets in month 1,2,13 and 14 of the treatment. No drug in 3rd and 4th year.
• # of Total Patient Equals who have taken the drug in a particular month are calculated by dividing standard units (SU) sold in that month by monthly dosage (considered as 6 tablets (SU))
• New patients taking drug in a particular month are calculated by subtracting the repeated patients number from the above number for that month. Repeated patients for a month are equivalent to new patients for the previous month.
○ We assume 100% compliance of new patients in taking the second dosage  and hence are accounted for next 12 months (next step)
• Final Total Patient Equals are calculated by summing up new patients number for recent 12 months i.e. the present month (for which the TPE are calculated) and the previous 11 months.
• Total Patient Equals share is calculated by dividing 'Total Patient Equals calculated using above methodology' by 'Sum of Total Patient Equals of all MS products'
Those should be the results:

Above requirements and formulas in cells are here ->
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xvItLMT8-BcoVjNR-NDIYUTlmTuebP-crD7foSFAwOM/edit?gid=1133570729#gid=1133570729
Here would be the test data:
  CREATE TABLE TESTOSS
   (    PERIOD_START_DATE date, 
    SU_VALUE integer
   );
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-SEP-17','DD-MON-YY'),69);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),263);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-NOV-17','DD-MON-YY'),684);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-DEC-17','DD-MON-YY'),938);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-JAN-18','DD-MON-YY'),1352);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-FEB-18','DD-MON-YY'),1174);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-MAR-18','DD-MON-YY'),1123);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-APR-18','DD-MON-YY'),1649);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-MAY-18','DD-MON-YY'),1402);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-JUN-18','DD-MON-YY'),1548);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-JUL-18','DD-MON-YY'),1448);

Could anybody please help me to resolve?
With Oracle it was resolved using MODEL clause
Translate excel formulas into SQL query
WITH METRICS AS
( 
  SELECT 
         PERIOD_START_DATE,
         PEQ,
         PREV_PEQ,
         REPEATED_PATIENT,
         (PEQ - REPEATED_PATIENT) NEW_PATIENT
  FROM
  (  SELECT PERIOD_START_DATE,
            SU_VALUE /6  PEQ,
            LAG (ROUND( SU_VALUE /6),1,0) OVER ( ORDER BY PERIOD_START_DATE ) REV_PEQ,
            0 AS REPEATED_PATIENT
      FROM TESTOSS
      ORDER BY  PERIOD_START_DATE     
   )
   MODEL
      DIMENSION BY (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD_START_DATE) RN)
      MEASURES (PRODUCT, PERIOD_START_DATE, PEQ, PREV_PEQ, REPEATED_PATIENT)

   RULES (
          REPEATED_PATIENT [ANY] =
          ( 
               CASE 
                    WHEN PREV_PEQ[CV(RN)]-NVL(REPEATED_PATIENT[CV(RN)-1],0) > PEQ[CV(RN)] THEN PEQ[CV(RN)] 
                    ELSE PREV_PEQ[CV(RN)]-NVL(REPEATED_PATIENT[CV(RN)-1],0) 
                END
            )
        )
)
SELECT 
        PERIOD_START_DATE,
        NEW_PATIENT,
        SUM(NEW_PATIENT) OVER(ORDER BY PERIOD_START_DATE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS FINAL_PEQ
    FROM METRICS
    ORDER BY PERIOD_START_DATE

But there is no MODEL clause in Redhsift.
Similar case was translated with Redhsift in
Translate excel formulas into Redshift SQL query

Your question is missing required details.  Please edit it and provide enough information for us to answer it.  For example, what is the expected result from the test data you supplied?  Where is your Redshift query attempt and explanation of how that attempt isn't working?  Please keep in mind that the entire content of your question needs to be within the question itself -- not linked.

Hello, you are right, my gsheet was missing grants to be read.

All the information required to help you needs to be in your question, not in some external link. You need to provide sample data, the result you want to achieve based on that data and the SQL you’ve managed to write so far - all as editable text, appropriately formatted. Then explain what the specific issue is with the SQL you’ve managed to write

I have provided missing details in the appropriate formats

@Kondjitsu You are not going to get much traction on this question as the table (alexandria.testoss) DDL is missing.  The error you are getting is about the use of NUMERIC (aka DECIMAL) data type but you question has no NUMERIC data as written.  This seems like a major omission.

Hello, @Bill Weiner, The DDL below is for table testoss. I have removed the schema prefix from the code and updated DDL from NUMBER to integer.
It should be complete now :)

The error you are getting is due UNIONing values of differing types.  "1.0*su_value /6" is of type NUMERIC of uncontrolled scale.  You need to take care of your types. I think you want float as you cast to this in other places.  This runs:
WITH recursive build (period_start_date,peq,prev_peq,repeated_patient, cur_rn, max_rn) AS
(
   SELECT period_start_date,
     round(peq,1),
     round(cast(prev_peq AS FLOAT),1),
     round(cast(repeated_patient AS FLOAT),1),
     cur_rn,
     max_rn
   FROM  (
        SELECT  period_start_date,
           peq,
           cast(prev_peq AS FLOAT),
           cast(repeated_patient AS FLOAT),
           row_number() over (ORDER BY period_start_date) AS rn ,
           2::INT              AS cur_rn ,
           count(1) over()           AS max_rn
        FROM  (
              SELECT  period_start_date,
                 round(1.0*su_value /6, 1)::float                peq,
                 lag(round(1.0*su_value/6,1 ),1) over ( ORDER BY period_start_date )::float  prev_peq,
                 cast(0 AS FLOAT)                  AS repeated_patient
              FROM  testoss 
            )
        WHERE  peq != prev_peq 
      )
   WHERE rn=1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b.period_start_date,
     round(b.peq, 1),
     round(b.prev_peq, 1),
     round(cast(
     CASE
        WHEN b.prev_peq - nvl(t.repeated_patient,0) > b.peq THEN b.peq
        ELSE b.prev_peq - nvl(t.repeated_patient,0)
     END AS FLOAT), 1) AS repeated_patient,
     b.cur_rn + 1  AS cur_rn,
     b.max_rn
   FROM  build b
   join
     (
        SELECT  period_start_date,
           peq,
           prev_peq,
           repeated_patient,
           lag(period_start_date) over(ORDER BY period_start_date)  prev_period,
           row_number() over (ORDER BY period_start_date)    AS rn
        FROM  (
              SELECT  period_start_date,
                 round(1.0*su_value /6, 1)::float                peq,
                 lag(round(1.0*su_value/6,1 ),1) over (ORDER BY period_start_date )::float  prev_peq,
                 cast(0 AS FLOAT)                  AS repeated_patient
              FROM  testoss )
      ) t
   ON  t.prev_period = b.period_start_date
   WHERE t.rn = b.cur_rn
   AND  b.cur_rn <= b.max_rn
)
SELECT period_start_date,
   peq,
   prev_peq,
   repeated_patient
FROM  build;

Also please run your test cases before posting.  You had syntactical errors.

Thank you, Bill, I was missing this little piece, great one!

If you'll undo the minus on a question I will mark it as resolved.
Btw, syntax was fine - after I've added ::float it returned results right away

Great to hear.  Recursive CTEs is a powerful tool for these situations in Redshift.

Hello, Bill!
So the resolution you've provided resolves the datatype mismatch, but I am still struggling to obtain a full dataset of results for all periods.
I have created another question for it -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79231932/recursive-sql-not-returning-full-scope-of-data
Maybe you'd like to challenge this one as well?
