Recursive SQL not returning full scope of data
I have a logic to calculate number of patients and med dosage per period, however my redhsift recursive SQL is not returning full scope of data:
WITH recursive build (period_start_date, peq, prev_peq, repeated_patient, cur_rn, max_rn) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        period_start_date,
        ROUND(peq, 1) peq,
        ROUND(CAST(prev_peq AS FLOAT), 1) prev_peq,
        ROUND(CAST(repeated_patient AS FLOAT), 1) repeated_patient,
        cur_rn,
        max_rn
    FROM  
        (SELECT  
             period_start_date,
             peq,
             CAST(prev_peq AS FLOAT),
             CAST(repeated_patient AS FLOAT),
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY period_start_date) AS rn,
             2::INT             AS cur_rn ,
             COUNT(1) OVER ()   AS max_rn
         FROM  
             (SELECT  
                  period_start_date,
                  ROUND(1.0 * su_value / 6, 1)::float peq,
                  LAG(ROUND(1.0 * su_value / 6, 1), 1) OVER (ORDER BY period_start_date)::float prev_peq,
                  CAST(0 AS FLOAT) AS repeated_patient
              FROM  testoss 
            )
        WHERE  peq != prev_peq 
      )
   WHERE rn = 1 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b.period_start_date,
     round(b.peq, 1),
     round(b.prev_peq, 1),
     round(cast(
     CASE
        WHEN b.prev_peq - nvl(t.repeated_patient,0) > b.peq THEN b.peq
        ELSE b.prev_peq - nvl(t.repeated_patient,0)
     END AS FLOAT), 1) AS repeated_patient,
     b.cur_rn + 1  AS cur_rn,
     b.max_rn
   FROM  build b
   join
     (
        SELECT  period_start_date,
           peq,
           prev_peq,
           repeated_patient,
           lag(period_start_date) over(ORDER BY period_start_date)  prev_period,
           row_number() over (ORDER BY period_start_date)    AS rn
        FROM  (
              SELECT  period_start_date,
                 round(1.0*su_value /6, 1)::float                peq,
                 lag(round(1.0*su_value/6,1 ),1) over (ORDER BY period_start_date )::float  prev_peq,
                 cast(0 AS FLOAT)                  AS repeated_patient
              FROM  testoss )
      ) t
   ON  t.prev_period = b.period_start_date
   WHERE t.rn = b.cur_rn
   AND  b.cur_rn <= b.max_rn
)
SELECT period_start_date,
   peq,
   prev_peq,
   repeated_patient
FROM  build;

it returns only one row of one period

instead of full scope of periods

This is the input test data:
CREATE TABLE TESTOSS
   (  PERIOD_START_DATE date, 
    SU_VALUE integer
   );

Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-SEP-17','DD-MON-YY'),69);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),263);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-NOV-17','DD-MON-YY'),684);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-DEC-17','DD-MON-YY'),938);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-JAN-18','DD-MON-YY'),1352);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-FEB-18','DD-MON-YY'),1174);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-MAR-18','DD-MON-YY'),1123);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-APR-18','DD-MON-YY'),1649);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-MAY-18','DD-MON-YY'),1402);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-JUN-18','DD-MON-YY'),1548);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-JUL-18','DD-MON-YY'),1448);
commit;

Could you please help me to correct this query?

The output you have shown is it the whole output?

What is the expected output?

Your code fetches just one row because you put the where clause condition to WHERE rn = 1 (Line: 29).
There are some other issues with the code too, and there is no explanation about the logic for the column repeated_patient.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :  
CREATE TABLE TESTOSS ( PERIOD_START_DATE date, SU_VALUE integer );

Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-SEP-17','DD-MON-YY'),69);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-OCT-17','DD-MON-YY'),263);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-NOV-17','DD-MON-YY'),684);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-DEC-17','DD-MON-YY'),938);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-JAN-18','DD-MON-YY'),1352);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-FEB-18','DD-MON-YY'),1174);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-MAR-18','DD-MON-YY'),1123);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-APR-18','DD-MON-YY'),1649);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-MAY-18','DD-MON-YY'),1402);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-JUN-18','DD-MON-YY'),1548);
Insert into TESTOSS (PERIOD_START_DATE,SU_VALUE) values (to_date('01-JUL-18','DD-MON-YY'),1448);

... the way I understood your question, one of the options is to create a cte with basic calculated data and later self join the cte by previous month/date and use case expressions to fetch what you want.
WITH 
  grid AS
    ( Select   period_start_date, 
               Row_Number() Over(Partition By period_start_date) as rn_month, 
               Count(1) Over(Partition By period_start_date) as cnt_month,
               su_value, 
               Round(1.00 * su_value / 6, 2) as peq, 
               period_start_date - INTERVAL '1' Month as prev_peq_date
      From     TESTOSS
    )

--      M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT period_start_date, peq, prev_peq, 
       Case When prev_peq > Coalesce(g2_next_peq, 0.00)
            Then prev_peq - Coalesce(g2_next_peq, 0.00)
       Else 0.00
       End as repeated_patient    -- this column is most likely wrong and you should adjust it ...
FROM (  Select      g.period_start_date, g.peq, 
                    Case When g.rn_month = g.cnt_month 
                         Then Round(Coalesce(g2.peq, 0.0), 1) 
                    Else 0.0 
                    End as prev_peq, 
                        LAG(g2.peq) Over(Order By g.period_start_date, g.rn_month Desc) as g2_next_peq
        From        grid g
        Left Join   grid g2   ON(   g2.period_start_date = g.prev_peq_date And 
                                    g2.rn_month = 1 And       -- joining first row of prev month
                                    g.rn_month = g.cnt_month  -- with last row of actual month (in case that is needed as your expected result shows multiple rows per month)
                                )
        Order By g.period_start_date, g.rn_month
     )

R e s u l t :



period_start_date
peq
prev_peq
repeated_patient




2017-09-01
11.50
0.0
0.00


2017-10-01
43.83
11.5
11.50


2017-11-01
114.00
43.8
32.30


2017-12-01
156.33
114.0
70.17


2018-01-01
225.33
156.3
42.30


2018-02-01
195.67
225.3
68.97


2018-03-01
187.17
195.7
0.00


2018-04-01
274.83
187.2
0.00


2018-05-01
233.67
274.8
87.63


2018-06-01
258.00
233.7
0.00


2018-07-01
241.33
258.0
24.33



fiddle

not really my friend:  WHERE rn = 1 fetches the first row, but then the UNIONed block is supposed to calculate recursively repeated_patient column provide rest of rows on the top of  rn = 1

@Kondjitsu Check it with and without rn=1 here ---> https://dbfiddle.uk/7DO-Y3s_
